# Union of glob_wildcards lists in Snakemae

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I am using Snakemake's global wildcards to receive input from files. 
I have two kind of files: a) fastQ files and b) assemblies (fasta).
I can use global wildcard to "read" fastq files and assemblies.

```
FASTQ, =glob_wildcards( unzip_res + "{fastq}_R1.fastq")#unzipped fastq files
GENOMES, = glob_wildcards( renaming_res + "{genomes}.fasta")#assemblies
FASTQ=set(FASTQ)#set of fastq files
GENOMES=set(GENOMES)#set of assemblies
```

How can I build the union of both sets to have all samples?
What is want is something like

```
    SAMPLES=union(FASTQ,GENOMES)# NOT Running. all samples
```

Answer (score 1):

Snakemake is build upon Python, and in Python you take the union of two sets with `|`:

```
SAMPLES = FASTQ | GENOMES
```

Or alternatively you could use:

```
SAMPLES = FASTQ.copy()
SAMPLES.update(GENOMES)
```

Whichever you prefer.